# mysql query to excel

Tags: php, mysql

Community,

I am currently working on a report builder.  The objective of the report builder is to send out an email with an excel document with weekly information coming from an sql table.  It is activated when the first person logs in for the day on Monday.  If Monday is a holiday, and no one logs in that day, a timestamp will not be made in the database.  When the user logs in Tuesday, it looks at the last timestamp to see if one was placed for the previous day.  if not, it will fire on tuesday.

The first step in this process looks like this...

```
$today = cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"));
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' -1 day'));
$holiday = false;
if(jddayofweek($today,1) == 'Tuesday')
{
    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select report_date from report_builder where report_date = '{$yesterday}'")) == 0)
    {
        $holiday = true;
    }
}
if(jddayofweek($today,1) == 'Monday' || $holiday === true)
{
    $today = mysql_query("select report_date from report_builder where report_date = CURDATE()");
    if(mysql_num_rows($today) == 0)
    {
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()-(7*86400));
        mysql_query("INSERT into report_builder (report_date) VALUES (CURDATE())");
```

//More code here

**The question for this particular post is as follows:

Is it possible to send the information to a csv file that does not actually open so the user can see, but instead be saved to a temporary file?  Can this be done in a way where it doesn't send the background html?**

Once this is accomplished, I wanted to send the file to a user using my current code that looks like this...

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From = "**********";
$mail->AddAddress("*************");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "HI";
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = addslashes($fileName);
echo $fileName;
$mail->AddAttachment("temporary file path");
if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo 'Message was not sent.';
    echo 'Mailer error:'.$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: You're posted lots of code that looks completely unrelated to what you ask (calculate Julian day? fetch from DB? send e-mail?) yet you've omitted all the code to generate the CSV file you're unhappy with. I honestly can't figure out what your problem is.

Comment: [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) a very good class for generating straight to `.xls` but has a steep learning curve..

Comment: I didn't say I had a problem with any CSV file.  Please read my question again and very carefully.  Obviously you did not read the introduction.  I have a mysql query which is gathering data from my DB (thus how the csv table is being populated).  I am trying to find a way to send that information to an csv document that does not open in the browser, instead if it can be saved to a temporary file which is then emailed to particular users.

Comment: @MackieeE , I was messing around with PHPExcel earlier.  One of the class structures doesn't work because it requires that I change php.ini which I unfortunately don't have access to.  At least, that is the info i gathered off of another Stack post.  I can discuss that further if need be.  However, unrelated to current post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can certainly write a files to disk and save it in any number of ways.  I will however point you to something that might be a quick way to save some steps (i.e. not have to create a file in PHP) if you application server and your MySQL are on the same physical host.  This is of course assuming that a CSV file would be suitable (i.e. you don't actually need to use a PHP Excel library to build an XLS or XLSX file)

```
SELECT [fields] INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM your_table;
```

This will directly create a CSV at location `path/to/file` on the machine which can then be sent via PHP.  Please note that the file name must not be an existing file name as this approach will not allow you to overwrite an existing file.

If your MySQL host is remote or you need to manipualte the data before writing to file, I would suggest looking at `fputcsv()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) in order to write the data from your query directly to a file in CSV format.

```
$file = fopen('/path/to/file.csv', 'w');

while ($row = [YOUR DATABASE FETCH HERE]) {
    fputcsv($file, $row);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of accomplishing that by having the server send it out automatically without having to script it using php?

Comment: @CBC_NS You are going to have to script it somewhere (doesn't need to be PHP, could be shell script or whatever). MySQL doesn't send emails.

Comment: Thanks, I was just curious if that was possible.